# Is it possible to get deducted amount of main account in android application?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I think I am asking a very basic question hare but I want to know is there any way to get the deducted amount of main account balance after making call on a number. If it is possible I would like to create an application that will show the call details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing functionality provided by android or Network provider,

Because you call charges make frequently up down while you subscribe special offers,

So there is only a way to get call charges is.....

1.) you must have to set your default call rate at one place.

2.) after while you cut the call you can get the duration of this particular call.it is possible.

3.) So you have to calculate this things(rates) manually, your self and
 map with particular number and store at one place and Display on UI.

Comment: Okay thank you :) , one thing more.. is it possible to read the notification or splash messages (call summary) containing deduction details after disconnecting calls?